# Swapping laptop HDD to Identical Laptop does not boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have 2x Identical Lenovo Thinkpads, Let's call them old & new.

My Old HDD has dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows via grub menu at boot

When I swap my internal HDD from my old thinkpad to the new thinkpad Grub menu does not come up and no OS boots, instead I see some Windows bitlocker menu come up.

I think I have all bios options configured the same in New as I see in Old but in the boot menu of Old there are additional options for Ununtu.

What do I need to do with New Laptop to get to boot like the Old Laptop using the Old HDD?

Thx

Tony

Comment: Go to the BIOS setup of the new laptop. Change boot order to Ubuntu /grub first. Disable bitlocker if enabled.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't show up in the boot order on the new laptop like it does on the old laptop.

Comment: Then your primary hypothesis that the two laptops are identical, is wrong. Without knowing what's different in the two laptops, it's difficult to troubleshoot. In any case, this is a hardware problem, not an Ubuntu problem.

Comment: Can you boot the new laptop from an Ubuntu installation USB (use the **Try Ubuntu** option)and see if the swapped hard drive is readable and writable?